# Segmentation fault with nested try blocks in C++Builder from Android

Tags: android, try-catch, c++builder

I working in C++Builder. Discover one problem and reproduced that problem with the code below

```
void __fastcall foo()
{
    int a = 123;
    try {
        try {
            throw Exception(L"asd");
        } __finally {
            int q = 7899;
        }
    } __finally {
        int b = 12;
    }
    int c = 123;
}
```

In this code give me segmentation fault after the first __finally. Please help me resolve this problem. Thank you in advance for help.

I try write this code in body of __finally

```
Exception* e = (Exception*)ExceptObject();          
if (0 != e && e->HelpContext != HelpContextIgnoreError) 
   throw Exception(e->Message, e->HelpContext);
```

This code working correct if one thread, in multithread applications can give me other thread exception.

Comment: The 1st code you have shown is perfectly fine. If the compiler is not acting correctly, then you need to [file a bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com) with Embarcadero. In the 2nd code, your use of `ExceptObject()` in a `__finally` block is questionable. But why would you `throw` a new `Exception` with the same `Message` and `HelpContext` as the original `Exception`? I'm not sure if `throw`'ing a new exception in a `__finally` while an `Exception` is already in-flight is a good thing to do, though. You could just modify the existing `Exception` if needed and let it continue to propegate

Comment: I found out yesterday that this problem is due to the Exception destructor in which an exception occurs and it says that when the stack is unwound and an exception occurs in the destructors, an abortion is called. But I dont know how to solve it.